# Programming Initialization

Tags: ios, swift, initialization, swift2, init

So what is a good rule of thumb for initializing values.  I use Swift 2.0 and am just curious as to if I am going to set 10 values at some point in code is it good to create the class so that it has 10 values set at initialization or should I do it later.

```
let button = Button(frame: CGRect, backgroundColor: UIColor, cornerRadius: Float, shadowPath: CGPath)
```

Or

```
let button = Button(frame: CGRect)
button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
button.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0
button.layer.shadowPath = UIBeizerPath(rect: self.bounds).CGPath
```

Which one is better practice?

Answer (score 0):

Generally I think it comes down to personal preference and specific requirements of the code, but as a rule of thumb I'd use the former: create the class with 10 values set at initialization.  This will allow you to check the individual values at any point in the code during debugging and compare current values to their initialized values.